# How can I specify the type of the loop variable in a for loop?

Tags: rust

I want to specify the type of `i` in this for loop. Visual Studio Code tells me that the type in `i32` but the number isn't that big so I'd like to change it to `u8`.

```
for i in 0..101 {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

I tried this:

```
for i: u8 in 0..101 {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
error: expected one of `@` or `|`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:2:10
  |
2 |     for i: u8 in 0..101 {
  |          ^
  |          |
  |          expected one of `@` or `|`
  |          help: maybe write a path separator here: `::`
```

What is the right way to specify the type?

Comment: You need to specify the type for the range, e.g. `0u8..101`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `i` inside the loop in a way that the compiler can infer `i` must be a `u8`, e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aff67d4758ad49e85f165d294315d0e9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to have a type annotation in a for-loop, because the for-loop expects a pattern, and a pattern cannot contain type annotations. See [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops) for more details.

Instead you can do one of three things:

#### Make the type of the iterator unambiguous

In this case, it would be:

```rust
for i in 0..101u8 {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80ea053b8e830087c7b985e34d955839))

#### Use an irrefutable pattern with the @-pattern

```rust
for i @ 0..=255u8 in 0..101 {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=02695cb67c72c783f5b35dd062b0b236))

#### Add a type annotation inside the loop:

```rust
for i in 0..101 {
    let i: u8 = i;
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42ef2f2dba63aab963cf46a9588e1d78))

Answer (score 2):

You could explicitly choose the type of any number by adding an underscore followed by the data type.

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..101_u8 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```